# Current app instance hide when Notification is click to open PDF file using intent. How to make that current app instance visible?

Tags: android, android-intent, pdf-generation, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

**App Flow**

1. After generating PDF by **app**, it notifies that the PDF file created using notification.
2. When notification is clicked, PDF file will be open using **intent**(other PDF reader apps such as Adobe Reader).
3. Then the PDF file will be open and on pressing back button, the **app** instance is hide( inplace of showing the **app** instance).

   ```
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
           .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
           .setContentTitle("Resume Builder")
           .setContentText("Creating " + fileName + " .pdf in progress...")
           .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
           .setAutoCancel(true);

   File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
           AppConstants.RESUME_BUILDER_FOLDER + "/" + fileName + ".pdf");
   Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);
   Intent resultIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   resultIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
   resultIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

   TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
   stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);

   PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder
           .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
   mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

   mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
           .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
   mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
   ```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: On pressing back button after PDF file open(example: by adobe reader)... current app instance is added to APPLICATIONS stack ... HOW TO MAKE CURRENT APP INSTANCE VISIBLE?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, your `Notification` opens the PDF viewer in a new task. How should Android know to return to your app after viewing the PDF?

You should have the notification open an `Activity` in your own app. That `Activity` can then start the PDF-viewer. When the user returns from the PDF-Viewer your app will be underneath.

Comment: Okey Got it..  Thanks David Wasser .